# Docker Ports and Airflow Tasks Test

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-webserver

I'd like to ask what's the meaning of this PORT setup?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Zqg.png)

Sometimes I get the "5555/tcp, 8793/tcp" part and sometimes do not. So what is the function of "5555/tcp, 8793/tcp" and how does it appear when I build my Docker container?

Second question, which Docker container should I execute if I want to use command "airflow tasks test"?

Thanks

I expect to understand Docker container better especially how to use "airflow tasks test" command